# How to change Display Alert default focus on a button?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms DisplayAlert. I have two buttons in it one is light blue and another is Darker blue. I guess it is focus effect causing the difference.
can I set focus as per requirement? I tried to search documentation but no luck.

```
 DisplayAlert("Caption", "Message", "Cancel", "Send");
```

Cancel and send are buttons on display alert. Default focus on Cancel.I want to switch focus to Send without changing position of buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that Xamarin doesn't (and will not) support providing focus to a specific button using a DisplayAlert since this feature [exists in iOS only](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/pop-ups/). Remember that Xamarin.Forms is meant to target all platforms, and not iOS only, and introducing a "focus" variable for a single platform would thus be a no-go.

What you can do, is to swap your two buttons around as you mentioned yourself.

If that is not an option, have a look at what you can achieve using third party libraries such as [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs).

If that doesn't help you either, you will probably need to write a Custom Control or use an [ActionSheet](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/pop-ups/) instead.

Good luck.